# Kafka Consumer from different group consuming from different partition of Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a scenario where I have deployed 4 instances of Kafka Consumer on different nodes. My topic has 4 partitions. Now, I want to configure the Consumers in such a way that they all fetch from different partitions of the topic.

I know for a fact that if the Consumers are from the same consumer group, they ensure that the partitions are split equally. But in my case, they are not in the same group.

Comment: Why are they not in the same consumer group? Can you change that and put them all in the same consumer group?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I had some crazy ideas in my head earlier. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want you need the consumers being in the same consumer group. Only in this case a "competing consumer" pattern is applied : each consumer receives 1 partition from the 4, so you have 4 consumers each one reading from 1 partition and receiving messages for that partitions.
When consumers are part of different consumer groups, each consumer will be assigned to all 4 partitions receiving messages from all of them in a publish/subscribe way.